# libharu compiled Android so, but can't load library

Tags: android, libharu

Now I compiled the libharu into so, but when I write the code :System.LoadLibrary, it can't work, the error message is:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libharu.so: findLibrary returned null

What's up?

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of `so` file? Are you sure it is in the `lib\armeabi` folder in eclipse?

You should load with `System.loadLibrary("libharu")`, not with `.so` extension.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I deleted the .so extension, but it still can't work, I think that my libharu.so may have something wrong.

Comment: To be clear, you didn't delete the extension of the file itself, only in the loadlibrary variable?

Answer (score 0):

What is the LOCAL_MODULE in your Android.mk file whie compiling? In my case it is            LOCAL_MODULE := hpdf. So it creates libhpdf.so file and you need to System.loadLibrary("hpdf");

Comment: I doubt the original questioner will answer your question, perhaps you should revise your answer to be a bit more timeless, since it's missed being timely.